# Превратить иерархичный массив в плоский

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
0 =>    [
            field1 = ...,
            field2 = ...,
            arr = [
                0 =>    [
                            field1 = ...,
                            field2 = ...
                        ],
                1 =>    [
                            field1 = ...,
                            field2 = ...
                        ]
            ]
        ],
1 =>    [...],
...
```

Если вкратце, то элементы полностью одинаковой структуры записаны иерархически. Для одних целей это удобно, а для других - нет, удобнее было бы работать с "плоским" вариантом. Есть какие-либо функции на `php`, позволяющие в таком случае "расплющить" массив, утратив его иерархичность.

Написать свой код проблем нет, но если есть готовые решения, хотелось бы о них знать.

---

Вот, что должно получиться в итоге:

```
0 =>    [
            field1 = ...,
            field2 = ...,
        ],
1 =>    [
            field1 = ...,
            field2 = ...,
        ],
2 =>    [
            field1 = ...,
            field2 = ...,
        ],
...
```

Comment: Добавьте вариант, который вы хотите видеть в итоге, не совсем понятна суть задачи

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Иерархия может быть любой длинны?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, уровень вложенности только один, но количество элементов не ограниченно.

Comment: И всё-таки. $массив[0]['arr'][0]['field1'] и $массив[0]['field1'] где должны оказаться в итоге и в чём между ними разница?